# Is there a way to detect if the cursor is inside an element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website, and I need to detect whether or not the cursor is within an element (specifically any div with the class `element`)
However, it's not as simple as that. I want to be able to detect which element is the one activating the function, and activate it behind an `element` div that the mouse is dragging around.

I've seen stuff like this before, but they didn't work behind other elements period, let alone an element that matches the conditions of the if statement.

I want the code to, when someone lets go of dragging an element, check if the cursor is inside another element behind it. If it is, delete the element the cursor was dragging around and change the text inside that element behind.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  var xoffset = 0, yoffset = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.parentNode.appendChild(elmnt);
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    if (???????) {
      //get that element and merge
      mergeElements(?????);
    }
  }
                    
  function mergeElements(behind) {
    //delete the held element
    elmnt.parentNode.removeChild(elmnt);
    //change the text on the element behind it
    behind.innerHTML = "MERGE TEST"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="gameboard">
  <div class="element">
    <p>TEST1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <p>TEST2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <p>TEST3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <p>LINE TESTING</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <p>OVERFLOW TESTING</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need more code, please say so. I'm not exactly sure what's really relevant or not.

Comment: What about listening to the [`mouseover` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete HTML example and pinpoint exactly what should happen in that example?

Comment: added the information you wanted (i hope)

Comment: I don't exactly know what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't know what more to say. i've explained everything i want in the post.

Comment: also @evolutionxbox would that work in this context? from the sounds of it, it'd run outside of the function i want it to. i only want to check at a certain time.